# String input in a loop. First input works good, and on other inputs it skips

Tags: c++

I need to write some program for homework, but I have some problem with string input.

The problem is that I cant do 2 >= input, it just skips it. I dont know why. I was hoping somebody can expain me.

My code:

```
for (int f1=0; f1<5; f1++) {
    temp_st = new Schulernoten();
    cout << "Name eingabe: ";

    name = "\n";
    getline(cin, name);
    temp_st->set_name(name);

    // note for informatik
    cout << endl << "Note Informatik eingabe: ";
    cin >> note;
    while (temp_st->check_note(note)) {
        cout << "Falsch eingabe: ";
        cin >> note;
    }
    temp_st->set_note_inf(note);

    // note for math
    cout << endl << "Note Math eingabe: ";
    cin >> note;
    while (temp_st->check_note(note)) {
        cout << "Falsch eingabe: ";
        cin >> note;
    }
    temp_st->set_note_mat(note);

    // ausdrucken
    cout << temp_st->get_name() << endl << temp_st->get_note_inf() << endl << temp_st->get_note_mat() << endl << endl;
}
```

Sample of my output:

```
Name eingabe: Depeche Soul

Note Informatik eingabe: 1

Note Math eingabe: 1
Depeche Soul
1
1

Name eingabe: 
Note Informatik eingabe: 2

Note Math eingabe: 1

2
1

Name eingabe: 
Note Informatik eingabe:
```

As you can see the first input works fine, and then it just sips leaving empty space.

How can I correct this? Thanks

Comment: You're not even checking if your input operations succeed.  Try `if (!(cin >> x)) cerr << "ooops!\n";` everywhere and you might start to get an idea where/why it's failing....  For what it's worth, your error is probably that note is numeric so `cin >> note` leaves a newline on the stream, then the next `getline()` reads that newline rather than the line where you've typed another name....

Comment: (You can call `ignore` to consume the rest of the line that note was on...)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. I forgot to flush cin>>'s.

This is corrected code:

```
for (int f1=0; f1<5; f1++) {
    temp_st = new Schulernoten();
    cout << "Name eingabe: ";

    name = "\n";
    getline(cin, name);
    temp_st->set_name(name);

    // note for informatik
    cout << endl << "Note Informatik eingabe: ";
    cin >> note;
    cin.ignore();
    while (temp_st->check_note(note)) {
        cout << "Falsch eingabe: ";
        cin >> note;
        cin.ignore();
    }

    temp_st->set_note_inf(note);

    // note for math
    cout << endl << "Note Math eingabe: ";
    cin >> note;
    cin.ignore();
    while (temp_st->check_note(note)) {
        cout << "Falsch eingabe: ";
        cin >> note;
        cin.ignore();
    }
    temp_st->set_note_mat(note);

    // ausdrucken
    cout << temp_st->get_name() << endl << temp_st->get_note_inf() << endl << temp_st->get_note_mat() << endl << endl;
}
```